# Why we concatenate variables.... without concatenate this can do doifferent variables

Tags: php

i am new in php programing can any one tell me plz what is difference between

```
$strJobs[$months] .= $jobs.",";
```

and

```
$strJobs[$months]  = $jobs.",";
```

is there any same result without concatenation... plz tell me thanks

Comment: In the first case, if the variable or array key is not already set, it will issue an E_NOTICE about an undefined variablem since you are adding to something that doesn't exist... So you must first verify that the variable isn't empty...

Answer (score 4):

`.=` is shortcut notation for concatenate + assign. Your first line is equivalent to

```
$strJobs[$months] = $strJobs[$months] . $jobs . ",";
```

Your second line will simply stick a comma onto the end of `$jobs`, and assign that new string to `$strJobs[$months]`, replacing whatever was there before.

Answer (score 0):

```
$strJobs[$months] .= $jobs.",";
```

is the same as

```
$strJobs[$months] = $strJobs[$months] . $jobs.",";
```

So it takes the new value (`$jobs.","`) and concats it to the existing value.

The second one just sets the value of `$strJobs[$months]` to `$jobs.","`

Comment: Thanks for clearly defined :) it makes more clear

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the PHP documentation on [string operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

`$foo .= $bar;` is the same as `$foo = $foo . $bar;`

Comment: Thanks for clearly defined :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, sometime, alternatives make life more happy..usually..

```
.=
```

used for concatenation + assignement...somewhere you got a long text to be concatenated..I will got most commonly used example for this as sending mail...we create body and concatenate PHP variables by this operator....

```
.
```

dot operator is normally used to combine a single variable with text .